# Linux: How can i grep text from string to string

Tags: linux, bash, grep

How can I get text using grep command txt that seats between two strings?

for example:

```
<--string 1-->
the text i need
<--string 2-->
```

the "the text i need" between the two tags is dynamic, therefor i need a command that will output text from "<--string 1-->" to "<--string 2-->"

Comment: will "the text i need" be always one line or it could be more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing "the text I need" is just one line, you should check that both string1 and string2 appear (Alex's solution only checks one thing).

A better solution would be:

```
grep -A 2 "string 1" $file | tail -2 | grep -B 1 "string 2" | head -1
```

Comment: you  cannot always assume the "the text I needed" is one line

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
grep -A2 "<--string 1-->" file | grep -v "<--string 1-->\|<--string 2-->"
```

or

```
grep -A1 "<--string 1-->" file | grep -v "<--string 1-->"
```

or in a single process:

```
sed '/<--string 1-->/,/<--string 2-->/!d;//d' file
```

or:

```
awk '/<--string 2-->/{p=0};p;/<--string 1-->/{p=1}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Awk for this.

Inclusive:

```
awk '/<--string 1-->/,/<--string 2-->/' file
```

Excluding the string 1 and 2 lines:

```
awk '/<--string 1-->/{flag=1; next} /<--string 2-->/{flag=0} flag' file
```

Here, a flag is set when '<--string 1-->' is found in the line, and unset when '<--string 2-->' is found.

You can also keep either the first or second line using:

```
awk '/<--string 1-->/{flag=1} /<--string 2-->/{flag=0} flag' file
```

or

```
awk 'flag; /<--string 1-->/{flag=1} /<--string 2-->/{flag=0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know that "the text i need" is always above or always below string 1 or string 2, you can use `grep -A 1 "string 1" $file | tail -1` or `grep -B 1 "string 2" $file | head -1`

Answer (score 1):

we need to know what is the line number for string1 and string2
we can use grep -n for that
then using head and tail we can get lines between string1 and string2
for example:

```
<--string 1-->
the text i need
<--string 2-->


start=$(cat file | grep -n <--string 1--> | grep -Eo [0-9]+)
finish=$cat file | grep -n <--string 2-->) | grep -Eo [0-9]+)
res=$((finish-start))
result=$(cat file | head -$start | tail -$res)
```

It is a little bit hacky, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

```
DATA=$(cat /tmp/file)
STARTVAR=$(echo "$DATA" | grep -n '<--string 1-->' | grep -Eo [0-9]+)
ENDVAR=$(echo "$DATA" | grep -n '<--string 2-->' | grep -Eo [0-9]+)
CALC=$((($ENDVAR - $STARTVAR) - 1))
result=$(echo "$DATA" | grep -A $CALC '<--string 1-->')
echo "$result"
```

Replace the `CALC=$((($ENDVAR - $STARTVAR) - 1))` line with `CALC=$(($ENDVAR - $STARTVAR))` if you want to include `'<--string 2-->'` in output

Answer (score -2):

```
grep word filename
```

Check grep on wiki.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Comment: the text between two trings is dynamic!